# Linux PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Hi I am now into something that keeps confusing me. The problem i have is that i transfer my Domain DNS into a Linux Hosting because of massive attacks, Before i was running my website into a xampp Apache for Windows. i put a Anti Ddos Software but it can't really mitigate the server attack everyday. until yesterday that we discovered that we have a 100 Million Attacks filtered by the Main Firewall. and our firewall gives up.

to make the story short i transfer my Website files into a Linux Apache Server to another hosting... but the MYSQL server stays on my Windows Server. i also change the port of MySQL server into something not related to the default 3306.. i made it 4444. the reason why i don't transfer MySQL is because this MySQL is connected into My Private Hosting of a Game. now all i want is to access the MySQL from Linux Hosting using PHP. Here is My Current Code for Connection

I paste into text file in my website here is the [Link](http://wydpilipinas.com/textfile.txt)

Note: I allow all Ports that is Necessary from Remote Connection, And i Close the Port 80 to Prevent Server attack..

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: surely your windows vps cant have an ip of `1.2.3.4` ?

Comment: does it work with the mysql client ? 
`mysql <user>@<url>:<port> -p`

Comment: at dbh. 1.2.3.4 is just an plain IP Sample instead of Showing my Real IP

@psal. I think its working because i make local Apache Php Server in my Computer using xampp and i turned off the MySQL in my computer so i can have the proof that i can really connect to the Remote MySQL Host

And i made it Work... My Computer Server Using PHP can get data from remote MySQL Host..